# Is there any javascript library that calculate content-type based on file extension?

Tags: javascript

Is there any javascript library that calculate content-type based on file extension?

Comment: Why? Both the javascript and presumably the file itself are client-side- so the client should know how to handle the data. And you can't rely on any details passed back to the server from any such script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any after a little searching but you could create your own by finding a [preferred mapping](http://www.sfsu.edu/training/mimetype.htm) and encoding them in an external JavaScript library like so:

```
// mime-types.js
mimeTypes = {
  'byExtension': {
    '': 'application/octet-stream',
    'ai': 'application/postscript',
    'aif': 'audio/x-aiff'
    //...
  },
  'byType': {
    'application/octet-stream': ['', '*', 'bin', 'class', 'exe' /*, ...*/],
    'application/pdf': ['pdf']
    //...
  }
}
```

A good text editor with macros or a simple shell script could do the majority of the encoding for you.